# MySqlDb Install Error: Python 2.6; Mac OS 10.6, XAMPP installed

Tags: python, mysql, xampp, mysql-python

I recently migrated to the world of Macs. And I'm trying to get my Django apps up and running. However, I'm having hard time in installing MySQLDb connector. I prefer using XAMPP hence dont have separate copies of MySql/Apache installations. I installed MySqlDb using MacPorts by executing following command:

```
sudo port install py26-mysql
```

It was installed without any issues. But when I try to run my Django app (with settings.py containing MySql database) I get following error.

```
    /Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py:60: DeprecationWarning: Short names for ENGINE in database configurations are deprecated. Prepend default.ENGINE with 'django.db.backends.'
  DeprecationWarning
Unhandled exception in thread started by <bound method Command.inner_run of <django.contrib.staticfiles.management.commands.runserver.Command object at 0x101112310>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 88, in inner_run
    self.validate(display_num_errors=True)
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 243, in validate
    from django.core.management.validation import get_validation_errors
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/validation.py", line 3, in <module>
    from django.contrib.contenttypes.generic import GenericForeignKey, GenericRelation
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/contrib/contenttypes/generic.py", line 6, in <module>
    from django.db import connection
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 78, in <module>
    connection = connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS]
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 93, in __getitem__
    backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 33, in load_backend
    return import_module('.base', backend_name)
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 14, in <module>
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading MySQLdb module: %s" % e)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module: No module named MySQLdb
```

Any help would be highly appreciated! :)

Answer (score 0):

Likely mysql-python is not installed (properly).

Answer (score 0):

Installing Mysql on OSX is an [involved process](http://hivelogic.com/articles/installing-mysql-on-mac-os-x/).